# mysql stored procedure and functions syntax errors

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I'm working in mysql workbench 8.0.11 and having problems creating stored procedures and also functions. Just to be clear, I am running this in mysql via the mysql workbench. I am not using any other program at all.

I'm trying to create a new stored procedure. I keep getting a syntax error: "delimiter" is no valid input at this position, expecting: CREATE.

I have checked the mysql website to make sure my syntax is correct, and it matches. Another thing to note is that I've tried starting the stored procedure with use accounting; (the db I'm working with) and I get the same error, except that "use" takes the place of "delimiter". So, I'm not sure it has anything to do with the delimiter keyword itself. Is there some setting in mysql workbench that I can set to get this straightened out? Also, I get the same exact syntax error when trying to create a function.

I have tried creating both a stored procedure and a function without using the delimiter keyword, or the use keyword, and when I hit the apply key mysql crashes.

Here is my code:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure 'add_expense_category' (id int, name varchar(20))
begin
insert into expense_categories(expense_category_id, expense_category)
values(id, name);
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? Settings to change? Anything?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you learn googling the error message with & without your particular names/strings?

Comment: EVERY statement must be terminated your insert is not. Pleas read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: My apologies, I missed the semicolon on the end of the insert statement. I did have that in the original code, just missed adding it here. However, that does not change the error. I continue to receive the same error message.

Comment: I have googled the issue tons and have not found anything relevant to my particular issue. Most of the issues I find that seem like they might be relevant end up being related to someone using php or another program.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
delimiter $$
create procedure `add_expense_category` (id int, name varchar(20))
begin
insert into expense_categories(expense_category_id, expense_category)
values(id, name);
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I missed adding the ending semicolon to the insert statement when I typed my code into the question. However, it was included in my original code. I get the same error with the semicolon as well. I also get it when I change the delimiter back to the semicolon.